# Equivalence of given norms in $\mathbb{R}^k$

Tags: normed-spaces

> Find as big as possible $c>0$ and as small as possible $C>0$ such that we have:
>   $$\forall_{\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^k} \ \ c\cdot \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^k|x_j|^2}\le \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^k \frac{|x_j|^2}{j}}\le C \cdot \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^k|x_j|^2}$$

I have been struggling with this problem for hours and I only found trivial equivalence constants: $c=\sqrt{\frac{2}{k(k+1)}}, \ C=\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{1}{j}}$ 
But they are not the best we can obtain. There is strict inequality for all $\vec{x}$ (except $\vec{0}$ of course) with them. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If $a_j$ and $b_j$ are nonnegative numbers, then 
$$(\min b_j )\sum a_j \le \sum a_j b_j \le (\max b_j )\sum a_j \tag{1}$$
Use this with $a_j=|x_j|^2$ and $b_j=1/j$.

The constants you get from (1) are guaranteed to be optimal, or your money back. (Seriously: if all except one $a_j$ is zero, and the nonzero entry is paired with the maximal $b_j$, equality holds on the right in (1). Similarly on the left.)